# Send data and files through multi-part forms with FormData in HTML using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In the below code, I'm able to transfer data but when I use the function append to transfer file and data it's not working. Can someone tell me how to transfer file from upload? Looking forward to some help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var loader = '<img src="../assets/media/loader.gif" />';

  $('#submit').click(function() {
    confirm("Do you really want to send messages?");
    $('.loading').html(loader).fadeIn();

    var msg_area_cst = $('textarea[name=msg_area_cst]').val();
    var num_cst = $('textarea[name=num_cst]').val();

    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data = 'msg_area_cst=' + msg_area_cst + '&num_cst=' + num_cst;
    form_data.append('upload', $('input[name=upload]'));

    $.ajax({
      url: "../server/CustomMsg.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: form_data,
      success: function(html) {
        if (html == 1) {
          $('#register_form').fadeOut('slow');
          $('.loading').fadeOut();
          $('.message').html('Successfully Sent ! ').fadeIn('slow');
        } else 
          alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you correctly declare a `FormData` object, but then in the next line overwrite it immediately with a string.

You need to `append()` ***all*** data to the FormData object. In addition you need to provide the file data to the `append()` method, not the jQuery object referencing the `input type="file"` control.

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('msg_area_cst', msg_area_cst);
form_data.append('num_cst', num_cst);
form_data.append('upload', $('input[name=upload]')[0].files[0]);
```

That being said, you can make this much more simple if the controls you're reading the values from are contained in a `form` element. Then you can use the `submit` event of that form and pass a reference to it to the FormData constructor.

Also you don't do anything with the result of the `confirm()` I assume you want to stop the form submission if `Cancel` is clicked, which the above example now does using `preventDefault()`.

Finally, using `html == 1` is very unreliable. Firstly `html` will be a string so relying on implicit type coercion to an integer is not ideal. Also, returning a plain text response can cause issues if there's any whitespace included. I'd strongly suggest you change your server side logic to return a serialised format, such as JSON, and use a boolean value for a 'success' flag.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$('#yourForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  if (!confirm("Do you really want to send messages?")) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  $('.loading').html(loader).fadeIn();

  $.ajax({
    url: "../server/CustomMsg.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    success: function(html) {
      if (html.trim() === "1") {
        $('#register_form').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.loading').fadeOut();
        $('.message').html('Successfully Sent ! ').fadeIn('slow');
      } else
        alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. When I tried to check the output of form_data in the console it shows FormData{   }

Comment: That's expected behaviour. You can't see the content of FormData in the console as it's binary encoded. Can you give more information than 'it doesn't work'. Have you debugged what's received in your PHP?

Comment: Thanks a lot after adding contentType,cache,processData,async it worked. But I didn't understand how it worked

Comment: It's because you need to append each value to the FormData object individually, using a key and value,  instead of adding a single form-urlencoded querystring. don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

**Try this ajax code**

```
  $.ajax({
     url: "../server/CustomMsg.php",
     type: "POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
         async: true,
  success: function(html) {
    if (html == 1) {
      $('#register_form').fadeOut('slow');
      $('.loading').fadeOut();
      $('.message').html('Successfully Sent ! ').fadeIn('slow');
    } else 
      alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But Can you explain why this works and the earlier one didn't